# Pandas, dataframe with a datetime64 column, querying by hour

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, datetime64

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which has one column constituted by `datetime64`, e.g.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1471 entries, 0 to 2940
Data columns (total 2 columns):
date    1471  non-null values
id      1471  non-null values
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(1)
```

I would like to sub-sample `df` using as criterion the hour of the day (independently on the other information in `date`). E.g., in pseudo code

```
df_sub = df[ (HOUR(df.date) > 8) & (HOUR(df.date) < 20) ]
```

for some function `HOUR`.

I guess the problem can be solved via a preliminary conversion from `datetime64` to `datetime`. Can this be handled more efficiently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a simple solution.

```
df['hour'] = df.date.apply(lambda x : x.hour)

df_sub = df[(df.hour > 8) & (df.hour) <20]
```

---

EDIT:

There is a property `dt` specifically introduced to handle this problem. The query becomes:

```
df_sub = df[ (df.date.dt.hour > 8) 
              &  (df.date.dt.hour < 20) ]
```

Comment: With Timestamp objects, this is now :`timestamps = pandas.date_range(start='2012-12-02 00:00:00', end='2012-12-03 23:00:00', freq='H')` and then `timestamps.hour` will return `Int64Index([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], dtype='int64')`