# extract hour from timestamp with python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, extract, hour

I have a dataframe  df_energy2

```
df_energy2.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 29974 entries, 0 to 29973
Data columns (total 4 columns):
TIMESTAMP        29974 non-null datetime64[ns]
P_ACT_KW         29974 non-null int64
PERIODE_TARIF    29974 non-null object
P_SOUSCR         29974 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 936.8+ KB
```

with this structure :

```
df_energy2.head()

TIMESTAMP P_ACT_KW PERIODE_TARIF P_SOUSCR
2016-01-01 00:00:00 116 HC 250 
2016-01-01 00:10:00 121 HC 250
```

Is there any python function which can extract hour from `TIMESTAMP`?

Kind regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need [`dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html):

```
print (df.TIMESTAMP.dt.hour)
0    0
1    0
Name: TIMESTAMP, dtype: int64

df['hours'] = df.TIMESTAMP.dt.hour
print (df)
            TIMESTAMP  P_ACT_KW PERIODE_TARIF  P_SOUSCR  hours
0 2016-01-01 00:00:00       116            HC       250      0
1 2016-01-01 00:10:00       121            HC       250      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your data:

> ```
> df_energy2.head()
>
> TIMESTAMP P_ACT_KW PERIODE_TARIF P_SOUSCR
> 2016-01-01 00:00:00 116 HC 250 
> 2016-01-01 00:10:00 121 HC 250
> ```

You have timestamp as the index. For extracting hours from timestamp where you have it as the index of the dataframe:

```
  hours = df_energy2.index.hour
```

---

**Edit**: Yes, jezrael you're right. Putting what he has stated: pandas dataframe has a property for this i.e. `dt` :

```
<dataframe>.<ts_column>.dt.hour
```

Example in your context - the column with date is `TIMESTAMP`

```
df.TIMESTAMP.dt.hour
```

---

A similar question - [Pandas, dataframe with a datetime64 column, querying by hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624217/pandas-dataframe-with-a-datetime64-column-querying-by-hour)

Comment: No, there is `RangeIndex: 29974 entries, 0 to 29973`, so your solution is wrong. `Timestamp` is column.